# docker mysql wordpress port doesn't connect

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker

I downloaded the mysql and wordpress images. Mysql ports are

3306 localhost:32781
33060 localhost:32780

Wordpress configuration is

WORDPRESS_DB_HOST 192.168.99.100:32774

MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD and WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD are the same

I try to connect to wordpress with

http://192.168.99.100:32774/

I get the message

This site can’t be reached

How do I have to configure the ports of mysql and wordpress?

CONFIGURATION MYSQL

[image]

[image]

WORDPRESS

[image]

[image]

Error trace

[image]

Comment: I think you should improve your question with more information, do you have any logs regarding the starting of wordpress container or if it connects to the mysql container? can you share the lines regarding docker run or the compose file? justo to make sure you are mapping ports correctly

Answer (score 1):

From what you can find on the docker configuration page, you should take this example and modify it to your needs.
There is the following docker-compose file that will launch a wordpress in a minute:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: "db:3306"
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
volumes:
    db_data: {}
```

From that file you have various options like, using docker compose tool (https://docs.docker.com/compose), or if you have a swarm running you could use docker stack command(https://vsupalov.com/difference-docker-compose-and-docker-stack/) or you can divide the configuration of both elements and create separate Dockerfile's(the configuration of a Docker file differs from what you can see on docker-compose so take the information an create your own) and launch them separated, you should launch mysql first as wordpress depends on a bbdd running first.

Comment: I work with kitematic. Attached the configuration of mysql and wordpress

Comment: Not trying to discourage you from using kitematic but is legacy and Docker recommends to use docker desktop instead https://docs.docker.com/kitematic/userguide/

Comment: On docker-compose, put quotes on it:
WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: "db:3306"

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to implement this is using docker-compose. Here is an example:

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  database:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - my_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wp_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - database
    image: wordpress:php7.3-apache
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: database:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wp_user
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password
    working_dir: /var/www/html
volumes:
  my_data: {}
```

A few notes: the database doesn't mount any port on host because it doesn't need to. If you don't want to use docker-compose you can run docker run commands for this but then you have to create your own network for the containers and attach them to it.

Wordpress will be available on http://localhost:8000.

WORDPRESS_DB_HOST is the connection to the database and you won't be able to access that through http anyway.

Hope this helps you.